# Leaflet Control doesn't give accurate sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I'm trying to recreate/redo the Leaflet sidebar created by [Turbo87](https://github.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar) since that version seems to be only legacy Leaflet and I need mine to be mobile friendly. However, with the current code I have now, the sidebar does not have a scrollbar to scroll to the text that would be off-screen. I know he did a version 2, but I'm more of a fan of this style, so I thought I would try to update it to a newer version of Leaflet.

I've gotten this bare-bones version that shows up when you click the button and displays the div as a "sidebar". However, the text does not come with a sidebar. I've tried setting the height and max height of the div, both in CSS and in the onAdd function, I've tried changing the overflow and overflow-y to no avail, and about all other solutions I could find. All I'm trying to do is ensure that the sidebar has a functioning scrollbar (since setting "overflow-y: scroll" gives an empty scrollbar).

This is my code (or a stripped-down version):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sidebar Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<style>
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .sidebar-content {
        display: none;
    }
    .sidebar-header {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #sidebar-interact {
        background: white;
        border: 2px solid #BAB3AD;
        border-radius: 8px;
        height: 50%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        width: 460px;
        margin: 2px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var sidebar;
    var sidebarButton;

    function initMap()
    {
        var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [51, 0],
            zoom: 16,
            zoomControl: false
        });

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
            maxZoom: 20,
        attribution: 'Imagery Â© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/" target="_blank">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'mapbox.streets',
    }).addTo(map);

    L.Control.Sidebar = L.Control.extend({

        initialize: function(id) {
            var options = {
                position: 'topleft',
            };

            L.setOptions(this, options);

            this._sidebar = L.DomUtil.get('sidebar-' + id);

            L.DomUtil.addClass(this._sidebar, 'sidebar-left');

            if(L.Browser.touch)
            {
                L.DomUtil.addClass(this._sidebar, 'leaflet-touch');
            }

            this._content = this._sidebar.children[0];

            var closeButton = "<center><input type='button' value='Close sidebar' onclick='sidebar.hide();'></center>";

            this._content.innerHTML += closeButton;
        },
        isVisible: function() {
            return L.DomUtil.hasClass(this._container, 'visible');
        },
        show: function() {
            if(!this.isVisible())
            {
                L.DomUtil.addClass(this._container, 'visible');
                L.DomUtil.get("sidebar-interact").style = "display: block;";
                L.DomUtil.get("sidebar-button").style = "display: none;";
            }
        },
        hide: function() {
            if(this.isVisible())
            {
                L.DomUtil.removeClass(this._container, 'visible');
                L.DomUtil.get("sidebar-interact").style = "display: none;";
                L.DomUtil.get("sidebar-button").style = "display: inline;";
            }
        },
        onAdd: function() {     
            var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'command');
            div.innerHTML = this._content.innerHTML;
            div.id = "sidebar-interact";
            div.style = "display: none;";
            return div;
        }
    });

    sidebar = new L.Control.Sidebar("1").addTo(map);

    L.Control.SidebarButton = L.Control.extend({
        options: {
            position: 'topleft'
        },
        onAdd: function() {
            var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'command');
            div.innerHTML = "<input type='button' id='myButton' value='Show sidebar' onclick='sidebar.show();'>";
            div.id = "sidebar-button";
            return div;
        }
    });

    sidebarButton = new L.Control.SidebarButton().addTo(map);
    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(document.getElementById("sidebar-interact"));
    L.DomEvent.disableScrollPropagation(document.getElementById("sidebar-interact"));
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='initMap();'>
<div id="sidebar-1" class="sidebar collapsed">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
        <h1 class="sidebar-header">
            My Header
        </h1>
    <p>A responsive sidebar for mapping libraries like <a href="http://leafletjs.com/">Leaflet</a> or <a href="http://openlayers.org/">OpenLayers</a>.</p>

        <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

        <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

        <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

        <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>        

        <p> Testing text</p>

        <p> Even more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="map" class='sidebar-map'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've gotta love graphic designers. A friend pointed out if I change the CSS for height from:

```
height: 100%;
```

to

```
height: 100vh;
```

The sidebar suddenly gets the scrollbar. After testing it for a it, after setting it to slightly less than 100 like the code below, it doesn't take up the entire bottom so we can have a margin.

```
height: 98vh;
```

Thank your nearest graphic designer.